# Operating System Development

Tags: operating-systems

I intend on creating a very basic operating system that does the basic stuff related to the operating system but don't want to work on low level program so was wondering if there was  the possibility for me to work on C/C++ and how to make a C/C++ program into an operating system, if it required any different kind of programming or procedure to do so, would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: should probably be moved to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: C actually *is* a low level programming language. @Logman: This question is too broad to be a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you: [How to Make a Computer Operating System](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Computer-Operating-System)

snippets from the link

- 3 Decide what you want your OS to do. Whether it is a fully capable OS
  with a graphical user interface (GUI) or something a bit more
  minimalistic, you'll need to know what direction you are taking it
  before beginning.
- 5 Decide if you would rather do it all yourself from the ground up,
  or if there is an existing kernel you would like to build on top of.
  **Linux from Scratch** is a project for those that would like to build
  their own Linux distro, for example. See Tips for an external link.
- 6 Decide if you're going to use your own bootloader or a pre-created
  one such as Grand Unified Bootloader (GRUB). While coding your own
  bootloader will give a lot of knowledge of the hardware and the
  BIOS, it may set you back on the programming of the actual kernel.
  See Tips.
- 7 **Decide what programming language to use**. While it is possible to
  create an operating system in a language such as Pascal or BASIC,
  you will be better off using C or Assembly. ***Assembly is absolutely
  necessary***, as some vital parts of an operating system require it.
  C++, on the other hand, contains keywords that need another
  fully-built OS to run. In order to compile an operating system from
  C or C++ code, you will of course be using one compiler or another.
  You should therefore read the user guide/manuals/documentation for
  your chosen C/C++ compiler, whether it comes packaged with the
  software or is available on the distributor's website. You will need
  to know many intricate things about your compiler and, for C++
  development, you should know about the compiler's mangling scheme
  and its ABI. You are expected to understand the various executable
  formats (ELF, PE, COFF, plain binary, etc.), and understand that the
  Windows proprietary format, PE (.exe), has been copyrighted.